# Asus N550JK Multimedia Keys not functioning

Tags: audio, windows-8.1, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I've got a (relatively) new Asus N550JK laptop - I've been using it for a few months but had no music on it - I just transferred all my music over from my PC and ran iTunes, then tried to pause the music with Fn+Down Key (which is the play/pause button multimedia key) but nothing happens.  It doesn't open any other program or give me an alert of any sort, it just does nothing.

Now all the other Function keys work, the backlight, monitor, volume, etc. are all fine - it's just those 4 keys (Stop,Play/Pause,Prev/Next) do not work - which makes me think that I probably uninstalled the program that it is actually associated with - and now the keys are useless.

Is there some way I can remap the keys? I tried going to keyboard in the Control Panel with no avail.

Answer (score 0):

[Driver download page for your Ultrabook](http://www.asus.com/us/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/N550JK/HelpDesk_Download/)

Just select the "ATK" driver from the list on the page above ^, install that driver.

Just in case you don't know how to do that: Unzip the file into it's own folder (right-click the zip file called 'ATKPackage_Win81_64_VER100031.zip', select 'Extract All'), then run the installer, then reboot.

Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help - I never uninstalled (or messed with) the ATK Drivers - I did follow the instructions and "repaired" the installation, restarted, and nothing changed.  I'll probably just suck it up and reset the laptop to factory settings before going back in and seeing if they work.